# Why Zeros not isolated in $ \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

My question is about two theorems 
1)isolated zeros theorem
Counter example in $\mathbb{R}$
Let
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{gathered}
   {e^{ - \frac{1}{{{x^2}}}}}.\sin \left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right)\hspace{2cm} x \in \mathbb{R}\backslash \{ 0\}  \hfill \\
  f(0) = 0 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$

the function satisfied that $C^\infty$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is Connected space but $0$ not isolated because there is a Sequence of zeros $U_n=\frac{1}{n\pi }$ , $n \in \mathbb{N^*}$ 
2)Liouville's theorem in complex analysis
$$ g(x) = \sin (x)$$
$g$ is $C^\infty$ and Bounded  but $g$ not constant 
My question is What the secret that make  theorems true for the holomorphic function in $\mathbb{C}$ and not true in differentiable function in $\mathbb{R}$? is the secret Topology and Neighbourhood  ?

Comment: different topics, really. The first example is not real analytic; as you know, the power series at the origin is the constant zero series, but the function disagrees. The second example is analytic, indeed $\sin z$ is holomorphic entire, and is unbounded along the imaginary axis. Holomorphic functions are allowed to be bound in some directions. See what you can find on the Airy functions  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function

Comment: Because complex analysis is the good twin and real analysis is the bad twin.

Answer (score 1):

These functions are $C^\infty$ and bounded on $\mathbb{R}$, not on $\mathbb{C}$. The key difference is that differentiability in $\mathbb{R}$ is a much weaker condition that in $\mathbb{C}$. A geometric way of seeing how much weaker the differentiability on $\mathbb{R}$ is than on $\mathbb{C}$ is to consider that on $\mathbb{R}$ you have a two limiting processes to consider, $\lim_{h\to0^+} (f(x+h)-f(x))/h$ and $\lim_{h\to0^-} (f(x+h)-f(x))/h$ while on $\mathbb{C}$ you have limits coming from uncountably many directions. My professors always highlighted this fact to show why $C^\infty(\mathbb{C})=C^1(\mathbb{C})\subset C^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1):

We could say that one of the main reasons holomorphic functions have more rigidity than $C^\infty$ functions is that holomorphic functions, if seen as functions from $U\subseteq \Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb C=\Bbb R^2$, are [solutions of a PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations).